# .NET (C#) Regex to only match printf()'s OUTSIDE of a specific if statement with non-fixed length

Tags: c#, c++, regex

I'm trying to write a .NET C# Regex to find printf()'s that lie outside of an if(Core_Debug) statement in several million lines of C++ code. The main problem is that there is absolutely no consistency between how these if statements were written and some contain more prints than others. Here's my test string to give you a scope of the problem:

```
if ( Core_Debug )
       printf("Query Thread ID = %x\\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
if ( Core_Debug ) {
       printf("Query Thread ID = %x\\n", GetCurrentThreadId()); //This should be negated by negative lookahead
}
if ( Core_Debug ) {
       printf("Query Thread ID = %x\\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
       printf("Query Thread ID = %x\\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
       printf("%lg\\n", value);
       printf("Query Thread ID = %x\\n", GetCurrentThreadId()); //\<- I want this to not match, it currently does not
}
if(Core_Debug){
printf("Query Thread ID = %x\\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
printf("Query Thread ID = %x\\n", GetCurrentThreadId()); 
printf("Query Thread ID = %x\\n", GetCurrentThreadId()); //<- I want this to not match, it currently does not
}
if(Core_Debug)
{
printf("%lg\\n", value);
printf("%lg\\n", value);
printf("%lg\\n", value);
printf("%lg\\n", value);
}

      if ( Core_Debug )
        printf("****type_of_service=%s\n", (char*)k_type_of_service);
    
            if ( Core_Debug ) {
               printf("Enable Table called\n");
               //printf("Enable Table called\n"); //This should be negated by negative lookahead
            }

printf("blah blah");
printf("blah blah");
//some important comment documenting everything
printf("blah blah");
sprintf(blah,"blah blah");
nprintf(blah,"blah blah");
xprintf(blah,"blah blah");
fprintf(blah,"blah blah");
cdprintf(blah,"blah blah");
goboldiegook();
//printf("blah blah");

goboldiegook(){
something;
printf("blah blah");
something;
printf("blah blah");
printf();
something;
printf(); // \<- I want this to match, it currently does not
}

    if (Core_Debug)
    {
        if (hw_present)
            printf("%s: HW is Present\n", mod_name.c_str());
        else
            printf("%s: HW is NOT Present\n", mod_name.c_str());
    
        if (sw_debug)
            printf("%s: SW Debug IS enabled\n", mod_name.c_str());
        else
            printf("%s: SW Debug is NOT enabled\n", mod_name.c_str()); //<- I want this to not match, it currently does not
    }
```

[This Regex](https://regex101.com/r/3hMCjY/1) was my first attempt at tackling this, and while I'll probably need to reuse bits and pieces of it to make it work, it has some issues:

1. Any printf() followed by (with whitespace between ignored) a } close bracket is ignored.
2. When I run the C# program on my machine with the bolded part of the regex (which was used to identify prints in the middle of a large if(Core_Debug){}), it stalls on certain files. I tried putting the file into regex101 as test string to see if there were any issues, but it seemed to run fine.

   "((?<!if\s*(\s*Core_Debug\s*)\s*|if\s*(\s*Core_Debug\s*)\s*{\s*if\s*(hw_present)\n\s*(|printf.*;\s*else\s*(|printf.*;\s*if\s*(sw_debug)\s*)))(?<!(if\s*(\s*Core_Debug\s*)\s*{)\s*|if\s*(\s*Core_Debug\s*)\s*{(\s*printf(.*);\s*)**{1,50}**)((?<!(s|n|x|f|cd)|//(\t| )*)printf(.+?(?=;))(?!;.*\s*}))"gmi
3. Despite the fact I wrote a check *specifically* for this particular case, the C# program still occasionally identifies the first 3 printf()'s in this code as outside of an if(Core_Debug){}. I again tried plugging in the file as a test string on regex101, but it returned absolutely 0 matches.

```cpp
    if (Core_Debug)
    {
        if (hw_present)
            printf("%s: HW is Present\n", mod_name.c_str());
        else
            printf("%s: HW is NOT Present\n", mod_name.c_str());

        if (sw_debug)
            printf("%s: SW Debug IS enabled\n", mod_name.c_str());
        else
            printf("%s: SW Debug is NOT enabled\n", mod_name.c_str());
    }
```

After this I tried playing around with [non-capture groups and conditionals](https://regex101.com/r/Q9BEwL/1) to see if I could make a better check for the Core_Debugs with brackets, and what I found is that while I could capture printfs that were specifically **INSIDE** the Core_Debug, I could not do the same for the ones **OUTSIDE** the Core_Debug.

tl;dr I'm looking for an easier way to do this (keep in mind no consistant formatting, so its **NOT** fixed length) in .NET (C#) Regex

```cpp
    if (Core_Debug)
    {
        printf("something"); //<- don't match
        printf("something"); //<- don't match
        printf("something"); //<- don't match
        printf("something"); //<- don't match
    }
    printf("something"); //<- match
```

Comment: You can't parse C++ with regex alone. Better use a full-fledged parser. Related: *[Parsing and analyzing C++ code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22956797)*, *[How to parse/simple analyze C/C++ code from C# to get a list of methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8817712)*, *[Parsing a c/c++/c# file in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34437686)*.

Comment: That's the thing about C++ scoping rules {} , you have use C# regex counters as well as matching all comments and all strings. This will get you outside of an _`if(Core_Debug){}`_ block to match printf() statements. I would have to clip pieces from my regex library. to put this C# regex together. Take some time to do this for free for a 1 off ...